# What's the meaning of the "Override working folders" checkbox in Visual Source Safe?

Tags: vss

When I do a check-in in Visual Source Safe, there's a checkbox "Override working folders" on that screen.

I can't figure out what the difference is between checking it or not checking it.

Comment: Please update your question with more details. At the time, it is not clear on what you have the problem, in which conditions.

Comment: @Gnoupi: He doesn't really have a problem, I think. Apart from the fact that there's something he doesn't understand ;-)

Comment: @fretje - Ok, I wasn't really understanding the meaning of the original question, in fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you're talking about this:

[image: screenshot]

From the Visual SourceSafe help file:

> **Override Working Folders (project-level Check In only)**
>   Overrides the working folder set for
>   the subprojects involved in a
>   recursive operation. This is useful if
>   you have some shared files checked out
>   in more than one project, and want to
>   check them all in at the same time.
>   Available only when you select the
>   **Recursive** check box.

It means that if you have set different working folders for different sub projects, the system overrides that and acts recursively as if only the top folder (on which you perform the action - check in, check out or get latest) has a working folder, and everything beneath it is also relatively beneath it on disk. Hope this makes it more clear.

By popular demand: an example:

If you have the following tree in Visual SourceSafe

```
   Main project ==> working folder = c:\MyProject
     |-- SubProject1 ==> working folder = c:\SubProject1
     |-- SubProject2 ==> no working folder
```

And a corresponding tree on your disk:

```
   c:\
     |-- MyProject
     |      |-- SubProject1
     |      |-- SubProject2
     |-- SubProject1
```

So when you do a Check-in on the MyProject level and you **don't** check the "Override Working Folders" checkbox, then the files to check in will be taken from:

```
   c:\
     |-- MyProject
     |      |-- SubProject1
     |      |-- SubProject2  <-- here
     |-- SubProject1         <-- and here
```

When you **do** check the "Override Working Folders" checkbox then the files to check in will be taken from:

```
   c:\
     |-- MyProject
     |      |-- SubProject1  <-- here
     |      |-- SubProject2  <-- and here
     |-- SubProject1
```

Comment: Maybe it'll be more clear with an example?

Comment: This answer helped clarify an issue I was having where I had subfolders set to different locations than the parent folder.  I then wanted to get latest in the hierarchical order they are in SS. --Thanks!